# GPU died and when a different GPU was put in to test it booted to windows instead of grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Recently I had a the GPU on my current rig have a bearing fail and I ended up killing the GPU attempting to replace the fan. I had to take it to a shop to confirm that it was the GPU and no other physical damage was the issue. They determined that it was the GPU by inserting another GPU I to the computer and they got it to boot into bios and then into windows, but the thing that is concerning me is that I had windows on the default drive it came with (it was a pre built rig) and I added my 2tb ssd with Ubuntu and made it the default boot drive. After the installation it booted to the grub menu every time and I could pick between the two no problem but they said that when they put the new card in the screen was black for a time then it booted windows. I ordered a new gpu, the same as the one that failed (different manufacturer same chipset) but it has not arrived yet and it's been nagging me why it booted to windows instead of the grub menu. Could the bios have chosen the windows drive because it was easier for compatibility with the card they tested or will I need to reconfigure the bios to boot from the SSD with Ubuntu on it and everything will be back to normal?

Comment: What usually happens when your Ubuntu can't boot using the installed proprietary graphics drivers is that it tries booting using the pre-installed built-in open source graphics drivers instead. Usually if your computer can boot Windows this means that it can boot Ubuntu too, but your case is obviously different.

Comment: Yea, I should have asked what card they used so I could have a better idea. This is the first time I've had GPU fail and my not quite sure how everything would react. I'm hoping the card since its the same as the last will simply boot like before since the drivers are the same as the last one but, the fact they were able to boot to bios means hopefully I can change any settings that may have changed, but it still perplexes me why it did not boot to the Ubuntu drive and was a blank screen until it booted windows.